# Java instanciate a class with String

Tags: java, oop

I have three classes, Foo and Bar and C, Foo and Bar extend C.

I also have a String s.

I want to know if there is a way to write the following program without 'if'.

```
C c;
if (s.equals("foo"))
    c = new Foo();
else
    c = new Bar();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `C c = s.equals("foo") ? new Foo() : new Bar();`

Comment: Is this a task from a course or a homework question? Can you add more details on what *is* allowed to use? I can give you an answer with `switch` / `case`, or maybe using a `try` / `catch`

Comment: I can't use any switches or ternary operator, forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is to know about any way to construct object via polymorphism based on a String argument, I believe you can leverage the ***factory design pattern*** [link](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method) here to accomplish your goal.

The factory class would have a creator like the following:

```
C createCobject(String str);
```

inside the createCObject you can do a checking of the string, and determine whether you want to construct a **Foo**() or **Bar**(). As both **Foo** and **Bar** are derived from type **C**, you can return any of these two types based on ***the passed String argument***.

Comment: By doing so, the checking of the string would mean using if or switch, which I want to avoid, even inside the createCObject.